# The remote host closed the connection

Tags: http, iis-7.5, logging, combres

We saw "The remote host closed the connection" in our error logs  with:

The error code is 0x80070040
The error code is 0x800703E3.(most of)

We are using combres for Javascript-Css minification, compression and cache.
Size of minified and compressed javascript file is 82.2 KB.

So is there any bug in combres or 82KB is too high for downloading ?

Also we try to make outputcache for .js files (those are prepared by combres), but it is not working. How can I reproduce the problem? In production environment we are getting errors but we could not reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of Combres.  This issue was reported [before](http://combres.codeplex.com/workitem/6547).  When I investigated it last time, it was unlikely a Combres' issue and it happened because the client disconnected in the middle of the request.  That seems to be congruent with the discussion in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831447/the-remote-host-closed-the-connection-in-response-outputstream-write).  If that is true, then that doesn't affect users at all, since they still see things unless they choose to, say, browse to another page.

Comment: "I was never able to reproduce the exception by canceling the download. We even tried disconnecting our network connection during the download. Neither caused the exception to fire. – spaetzel"  on that thread. We could not caused the exception to fire.

Comment: Tried put a Thread.Sleep() before the Flush() in the engine class.  That should give you enough time to disconnect before the Flush() is executed.  Otherwise it would be hard to reproduce unless you get the lucky timing.

Comment: Thx for greate product (combres) but i think there is no solution for this problem. Maybe ignoring that kind of errors is solution :)