# JMeter stress testing - server error is "The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD"

Tags: jmeter, asp.net-web-api2

When I try to stress load my ASP MVC Web API 2 by JMeter - an error occurred in the server side.
Here the **server** error:

```
2015-07-20 16:11:02.2636 ERROR 81 System.Web.HttpException (0x800704CD): The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD.
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
   at System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at MyApp.Export.Impl.MyExport.Export[T,V](Stream stream, Func`2 transferFunc)
   at MyApp.Controllers.MyController.<>c__DisplayClass3.<MyReturnResponse>b__0(Stream outputStream, HttpContent httpContent, TransportContext transportContext)
```

**JMeter** give me an error :

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

I read a lot of information about it. There are some assumptions about proxy server and et al.
Could you give me advice or solution for these errors?
May be JMeter is closing the content downloading?
Thanks a lot!

P.S.: also I already read the article [The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564862/the-remote-host-closed-the-connection-the-error-code-is-0x800704cd)

**EDITED** : I completed the test on Azure VM and it passed successful!

Answer (score 0):

Check any component between JMeter and your server:

- Firewall is the biggest suspect
- Load Balancer