# "Remote server closed the connection before sending response header" - iOS 10.3 issues

Tags: ios, ios10, ios11, charles-proxy, no-response

I have setup Charles proxy to test my app calls. I am getting following error in Charles proxy for iOS 10.3 where in iOS 11.3 it is giving me the success response.

Error:
**Remote server closed the connection before sending response header**

I am confused why it is not working for iOS 10.3? Is there anything different in iOS 11?

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831447/the-remote-host-closed-the-connection-in-response-outputstream-write/71270909#71270909)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on iOS 10.3 or later, open **Settings** and navigate to **General > About > Certificate Trust Settings**, and find the Charles Proxy certificate, and switch it on to enable full trust for it.

https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT204477

Comment: I have already done that. But it seems it doesn't resolve the issue.